# Validation Error Crashes App

Tags: node.js, mongoose, koa

I am using Koa and Mongoose for my REST API. My goal is to respond with the appropriate status code and error message. However, the app cashes on ValidationError, email is a required field but not given in this request. How do I respond with a status code other than 500.

```
router.post('/user/', function *() {
    var user = new User(this.request.body);
    yield user.save((error) => {
      if (error) {
        //Does not respond with a 404
        this.status = 404;
      } else {
        this.status = 201;
        this.response.body = user;
      }
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the great things about using `yield` is that you can use `try {} catch() {}` just as if you were writing synchronous code.

So your code becomes:

```
router.post('/user/', function *() {
  var user = new User(this.request.body);

  try {
    yield user.save();
  }
  catch (err) { 
    //Does not respond with a 404
    this.status = 404;
  }

  this.status = 201;
  this.response.body = user;

});
```